# Understand g++ linker failure

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++

Given a static library that you can inspect with

```
$nm libgtest.a
```

Why would the following build fail to find symbols?

```
g++ -ISomePathToGTest -lgtest SomeUnitTests.cpp
```

One of the many undefined references looks like this:

```
SomeUnitTests.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)'
```

But I have these lines from the 'nm' command above:

```
000000000000ffca T _ZN7testing14InitGoogleTestEPiPPc
000000000000ffca T _ZN7testing14InitGoogleTestEPiPPw
```

Which, according to the manual for nm, the 'T' means that this system is in the text section of the library I'm inspecting. I'm certain it's not picking this library up from anywhere else, and that it is finding this library I'm using with that build command.

Building just the object for SomeUnitTests.cpp like this:

```
g++ -c -ISomePathToGTest SomeUnitTests.cpp
```

And inspecting it with nm shows only this entry below for a search on InitGoogleTest:

```
U _ZN7testing14InitGoogleTestEPiPPc
```

So, they should match right? But, Focusing on how the linker is matching symbols and not that I'm working with gtest, why is it failing?

Comment: Did you try `g++ SomeUnitTests.cpp -ISomePathToGTest -lgtest`, i.e. libraries last?

Comment: Ah man, no I didn't and it worked! I really expected the g++ commandline to follow the manual example with 'infile' at the end. So how come that made a difference to the linking order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplifying for the sake of clarity, your commandline:

```
g++ -ISomePathToGTest -lgtest SomeUnitTests.cpp
```

invokes the `g++` tooldriver to do the following:

1. Invoke the GNU C++ compiler `cc1plus` to compile `SomeUnitTests.cpp` to
   a temporary assembly language file, with a commandline essentially like:

   `cc1plus -ISomePathToGTest SomeUnitTests.cpp -o /tmp/aaaa.s`
2. Invoke the GNU assembler `as` to assemble `aaaa.s` to
   a temporary object file, with a commandline essentially like:

   `as -ISomePathToGTest -o /tmp/bbbb.o /tmp/aaaa.s`
3. Invoke the GNU linker `ld` to link `bbbb.o` with the specified
   and default libraries, with a commandline essentially like:

   `ld -L/default/library/search/paths... -lgtest /tmp/bbbb.o -lstdc++ -lother -ldefault -llibraries...`

In the linker commandline, the ordering of the object files and the specified libraries
reflects that of the corresponding source files and the specified libraries in your
original commandline: because the ordering of object files and libraries *matters*
to the linker, and `g++` works on the assumption that you know this, and that
the commandline expresses the order you want.

The ordering of object files and libraries matters to the linker because
it will search a library to find a definition of some symbol `foo` if
and only if some object file (or library) it has already seen makes
undefined references to `foo`; and if it finds a definition in a library
then it will not search later libraries for other definitions of it.

A consequence of this is that a library must be mentioned *after* all object
files that make references into it, or undefined references will ensure. In
the linkage of your commandline, `libgtest` is not examined by the linker
at all, because so far no object files have been seen and there are no
undefined symbols to resolve. When the object file `/tmp/bbbb.o` is
subsequently examined, its undefined references can only
get definitions in the default libraries that follow, leaving all references
to `libgest`'s symbols unresolved.

Now you see the answer to your question why moving `-lgtest` to the end of
the commandline "changes the linking order". It's because *that's what you're
asking for*: instead of *library object-file* (fail), you are asking for *object-file library* (succeed).

Here is [the linker's commandline manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options).
The documentation for `-l namespec` is the relevant item.